# Will docker compose version upgrade cause downtime for running containers?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, version, upgrade

I need to reserve GPU for a docker service in the Linux server. Current docker compose version is 1.19.0 and GPU support need 1.28.0+. The upgrade need to uninstall and reinstall  docker-compose as per docker documentation. My doubt is whether this process cause downtime for other running containers in the server ? If so what is the expected downtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. If you do the upgrade as fresh install then it won't affect the running containers. Just run the below code. No need to remove existing docker compose and install latest version

```
pip install docker-compose
```

During this upgrade procedure no outages occurred for the running containers.